# Serve NextJS static export inside existing Laravel project under specific path

Tags: laravel, next.js

I have an already existing laravel project. Now I want to serve the nextjs statically generated files inside my laravel project with route something like [www.mylaravelproject.com/my-next-app](http://www.mylaravelproject.com/my-next-app). I know how to do it with vanilla Reactjs but not with Nextjs as there will be many pages like Login.html, About.html, Profile.html etc. I have searched everywhere but didn't find any solution.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to serve NextJS static exports inside an existing Laravel project under a specific path.

First, you need to generate the static files for your NextJS app using the command "npm run export" or "yarn export" depending on which package manager you are using. This will create a "out" folder that contains all the generated static HTML pages.

Then, you can copy the contents of the "out" folder into a new folder inside your Laravel project, let's say "public/my-next-app". Make sure that the folder structure is maintained, i.e., each page should have its own folder with an "index.html" file inside it.

Finally, you need to modify your Laravel routes to serve the static HTML pages from the "public/my-next-app" folder. You can achieve this by adding the following route:

Route::get('my-next-app/{any?}', function () { return file_get_contents(public_path('my-next-app/index.html')); })->where('any', '.*');

This route will match any URL that starts with "my-next-app" and serve the corresponding static HTML file. If the URL doesn't match any file, it will serve the "index.html" file by default.

That's it! Now you can access your NextJS app under the URL "www.mylaravelproject.com/my-next-app".

Comment: Suppose we have 10-20 pages.. Creating each folder for html pages generated would be a lot of work. Also each request will go through laravel routing which in turn would cause page refresh which is opposite of using a framework like nextjs. Is there any other way?